# Xamarin ViewCellRenderer Not Setting Background Color Consistently

Tags: c#, ios, uitableview, listview, xamarin

Weird one here. In Xamarin Forms (iOS), I made a custom ViewCell for my project to create a custom ListView look. For the most part, it works great. However, I'm running into a funky glitch. If the user taps a cell, the background color is changed as it should (see code below). From that point, I can also programmatically set the SelectedItem and the newly selected cell will show the custom background color. However, when I first start the app, before the user has a chance to tap an item in the ListView, I load up some preferences and manually set the SelectedItem in my UI startup routine. The SelectedItem does in fact change, but the code to set the background color has no effect. I can set the SelectedItem multiple times, and no color change. Once the user physically taps the ListView, the color lights up, and any subsequent changes to SelectedItem, whether manually or physically, work just fine. It's as if the user needs to interact with the ListView directly through the UI to get the background color to work. It also works if the user interacts with a different control that fires an event which then sets the ListView's SelectedItem. **Summary:** It doesn't work until the user interacts through the UI to set the SelectedItem. From there on out, everything's cool. Until then, no programmatic call to change the SelectedItem changes the background color (though a watch on the property does in fact reflect that it's been set.)

Very confusing... Sorry! Let me know what I need to clarify. The pertinent code is this:

**XAML**

```
<ListView x:Name="listSoundScapes" BackgroundColor="#101010" SeparatorColor="#202020" RowHeight="50" Margin="0" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" ItemSelected="listSoundScapes_ItemSelected">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
         <local:ExtendedViewCell SelectedBackgroundColor="#999999" Tapped="listSoundScapes_Tapped">
             <ViewCell.View>
                 <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">
                 <StackLayout HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" Orientation="Vertical" Margin="8,8,8,8">
                    <Label Text="{Binding Name}"
                       TextColor="#f0f0f0"
                       FontSize="13"
                    />
                    <Label Text="{Binding Description}"
                       TextColor="#a0a0a0"
                       FontSize="11"
                    />
                 </StackLayout>
                 <StackLayout x:Name="ItemCommands" Orientation="Horizontal" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" Padding="8" IsVisible="false">
                    <Button Image="edit.png" Clicked="btnEditSoundScape_Clicked" VerticalOptions="Center"  />
                    <Button Image="delete.png" Clicked="btnDeleteSoundScape_Clicked" VerticalOptions="Center"  />       
                 </StackLayout>
              </StackLayout>
           </ViewCell.View>                                
        </local:ExtendedViewCell>
     </DataTemplate>
  </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

**C#**

```
public class ExtendedViewCell : ViewCell
{
    public static readonly BindableProperty SelectedBackgroundColorProperty =
        BindableProperty.Create("SelectedBackgroundColor",
                                typeof(Color),
                                typeof(ExtendedViewCell),
                                Color.Default);

    public Color SelectedBackgroundColor
    {
        get { return (Color)GetValue(SelectedBackgroundColorProperty); }
        set { SetValue(SelectedBackgroundColorProperty, value); }
    }
}
```

**iOS**

```
[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedViewCell), typeof(ExtendedViewCellRenderer))]
namespace RootTuner.iOS
{
    public class ExtendedViewCellRenderer : ViewCellRenderer
    {
        public override UITableViewCell GetCell(Cell item, UITableViewCell reusableCell, UITableView tv)
        {
            var cell = base.GetCell(item, reusableCell, tv);
            var view = item as ExtendedViewCell;
            cell.SelectedBackgroundView = new UIView
            {
                BackgroundColor = view.SelectedBackgroundColor.ToUIColor(),
            };
            return cell;
        }
    }
}
```

To set the SelectedItem, I just do a basic, simple MyListView.SelectedItem = itmVariableHere; -- Nothing fancy.

Any leads to poke around with would be great. Again, let me know what I should clarify to make the question clear.

Thanks!

Comment: The color changes without any interaction on listview on my side , how do you set selectItem, please attach the code.

Comment: @ColeXia-MSFT - Thanks for the comment. Your comment convinced me that there must have been something in my code/logic, which it was. Dumb glitch, but painful to find in a large project. Thanks for leading me back on the right path!